# Reading specific fields from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read contents of a CSV file but I get NAN for some 'reviewtext' field. 
I have attached my csv file. When data.head() reads all values from the file but when I try to read only specific fields with revs.head() , it gives me an error.
[revs.head()Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFr87.png)   [data.head()Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLczj.png)

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.read_csv('Review_50.csv',sep='|',error_bad_lines=False)
 print data.head()
 revs = data.loc[:,['r_name','reviewtext','date']]
 print revs.head()`
```

[Reviews_50.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSiacAtZiR3u5tekUVjI_78fz6jYrz1E4ejoTVpjNM0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is problem in `6.` row all data are in first cell.

Comment: Yes. They are in first cell and seperated by "|"  delimeter. I want to read certain fields from that.

Comment: Do you want filter columns in `read_csv` ?

Comment: If need seelct some values use `df = data[['r_name','reviewtext,,,','date']]` and for columns names use `print (data.columns.tolist())` - get keyerror if want select column which does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in 6. row all data are in first cell.

Solution is or manually correct it or parameter `quoting=3` and then remove trailing `"` in first and last columns by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('Reviews_50 - Sheet1.csv',sep='|',error_bad_lines=False, quoting=3)

data.iloc[:, [0,-1]] = data.iloc[:, [0,-1]].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('"'))
print (data)

      City                      Name  Review No.         r_name  \
0  chennai                  Mridhuna         421  Writer's Cafe   
1  chennai                Adeeb Shah         422  Writer's Cafe   
2  chennai                       N T         423  Writer's Cafe   
3  chennai  Vanthian Balasubramaniam         424  Writer's Cafe   
4  chennai              Sukanya Kaur         416  Writer's Cafe   
5  chennai           Priya Dharshini         417  Writer's Cafe   
6  chennai                    Dhivya         418  Writer's Cafe   
7  chennai            Hari R Krishna         419  Writer's Cafe   
8  chennai          Brinda Vasudevan         420  Writer's Cafe   

   No of Reviews  Following  \
0            NaN          0   
1           13.0          0   
2           53.0          0   
3            NaN          0   
4           75.0          0   
5           10.0          0   
6           75.0          0   
7            2.0          0   
8            2.0          0   

...
...
...
```

Comment: jezral: My data.head() also returns me the values. I don't know why **data.loc[:,['r_name','reviewtext','date']]** gives me an error. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: I  dont understand, is there some problem?

Comment: Yes. I have uploaded pics of the error when I try to use **data.loc[:,['r_name','reviewtext','date']]**

Comment: Yes, check comment under question